# what is the wrong with this android code?

Tags: android

```
    VideoView video1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video1);
    SeekBar seekBar2e=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

    Uri aaa=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + G.name1 "/"+ taxidriver2 );
    **video1.setVideoURI(aaa);**
    video1.start();
```

Comment: what is the error???

Comment: Please consider adding infomation of what is wrong. E.g. it is crashing. And a logcat, so we can see why

Comment: I  don't think `**video1.setVideoURI(aaa);**` is valid Java code. If you're trying to make a comment, place `//` in front. Or is that suposed to be bold markdown for the question qnd not in your actual code? Pleqse give more information and write a more informative title.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
VideoView videoView;
        setContentView(R.layout.video_activity);
        videoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vidProfile);

        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.videoexample/"+R.raw.try_it;
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(uriPath);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
```

hope it will help

Comment: Code only answers are usually not very helpful. Please consider adding information as to what you have changed, and why. Where the error was in his origional code. etc